# Banach density of a sequence of spheres in a virtually nilpotent group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, ergodic-theory, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely-generated group of polynomial growth equipped with the word metric (with respect to a fixed symmetric generating set).

Let 
\begin{equation*}
A = \left\{ g \in G: |g| = mn, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
\end{equation*}
for some fixed integer $m \geq 2$.

$A$ is therefore a nested sequence of spheres in $G$.

Is there a constant $c$, perhaps depending on the growth function but independent of $g$, so that 
\begin{equation*}
c\frac{ \#\left(B_k \cap A \right)}{\#B_k} \geq \frac{ \#\left(gB_k \cap A \right)}{\#B_k},
\end{equation*}
where $B_k$ is the ball of radius $k$?

Comment: $A$ is not a sequence, it is an union of a sequence

Comment: Also I guess you want $c$ independent of $k$.